# Excel: Populate drop-down with [unique cells of column_A, where column_B value = SomeValue]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm very new to Excel, but I have the following situation:

I have Sheet1 which contains:

- user-entered numeric values in `column_A`
- user-selected YES/NO dropdown list in `column_B`, which references a two-item list (YES,NO) on a hidden `Sheet3`.

I have `Sheet2` which is to contain:

- A user-selected drop-down containing all unique values in `Sheet1:column_A` for rows where the user has chosen to select "YES" to the YES/NO dropdown in `Sheet1:column_B`.

So far, I have a named list `Column_A_Values` with the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(`Sheet1`!$A$1,0,0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000)+99)
```

On a hidden `Sheet3`, I have the following formula in `Sheet3!column_B` which attempts to generate a list of unique values where the user has chosen to select "YES" to the YES/NO dropdown list in `Sheet1:column_B`. This doesn't work, but I believe it's on the right track:

```
=INDEX(Column_A_Values,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:$B15,Column_A_Values)+("YES"<>Sheet1$B15),0))
```

Finally, I have a dropdown list on sheet2 referencing a named list containing the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!$B$2, 0,  0, COUNT(IF(Sheet3!$B$2:$B$1000="", "", 1)), 1)
```

I apologize if any of this isn't clear, and will clarify wherever necessary. I would appreciate any assistance anyone is willing to provide. I have not been able to get the 2nd formula working correctly, so that is my priority, but I am am also grateful for any advice you might have regarding superior approaches to obtain the bulleted functionality for `Sheet2`. Again, I am very new to Excel, but I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* *Array Formula* Type of Solution you can try:

**1** **Index - SumProduct Formula**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Column_A_Values,(SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(--(Column_B_Values="YES")*ROW(Column_A_Values),COUNTIF(Column_B_Values,"<>"&"YES")+ROW(A1))))),"")
```

But if it doesn't matter for you whether go by Array Formula or not, here are some another functions, as a different options than what dear @**A.S.H** has suggested.

**2** **Index Formula** - Array Series

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Column_A_Values,(SMALL(IF(Column_B_Values="YES",ROW(Column_A_Values)),ROW(A1)))),"")
Don't Forget to End your function by clicking ctrl+shift+enter, that's really important.
```

**3** --- **Offset Formula** - Array series

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,SMALL(IF(Column_B_Values="YES",ROW(Column_B_Values)-MIN(ROW(Column_B_Values))+1),ROWS($1:1))-1,0),"")
Don't Forget to End your function by clicking ctrl+shift+enter, that's really important.
```

> **In these examples the only thing you need to do is defining `Column_B_Values`as your `Yes/No Column` in `Sheet1 - Column_B`
>   **

Then as @A.S.H has mentioned again, your named list for the validation can be set to this formula:

`=OFFSET(Sheet3!$B$2,0,0, COUNT(Sheet3!$B:$B))`

Comment: Wow, so many options on the menu :). It's very good to have some non-array options.

Answer (score 2):

To generate the list of unique values from `Column_A_Values` in column B of Sheet3, type this *array formula* at `Sheet3!B2` then copy/paste down the column for a sufficient number of rows:

```
Sheet3!B2:
=IFERROR(INDEX(Column_A_Values, MATCH(1,
  (OFFSET(Column_A_Values,0,1)="Yes")*(COUNTIFS(B$1:B1,Column_A_Values)=0),
   0)),"")

Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Finally, your named list for the validation can be set to this formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!$B$2,0,0, COUNT(Sheet3!$B:$B))
```